# Get Selected Option Element in <select>

Tags: jquery, html, css, select

I have a `select` tag with multiple options, and the `first-child` is the initial value.

Lets consider the following example. The value `make` is the initial value.

Now what I am looking for is, When a value selected(`toyota`) it should change the color of both `select` tag and `selected option`.To make it more clear, just follow the following scenario.

When the initial value selected it should follow the following color code,

1. `Select` tag gets `green`.
2. `Option` tag gets `blue`.
3. `selected option` gets `blue` since it is the initial value.

When a value selected except initial text(make), it should follow the following color code,

1. `Select` tag gets `red`.
2. `Option` tag gets `blue`.
3. `selected option` gets `red`.

```css
select {
  color: green;
}

select.active option {
  color: blue;
}

select.active option[selected="selected"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<select class="make active">
  <option value="">Make</option>
  <option value="">Saab</option>
  <option value="" selected="selected">Toyoto</option>
  <option value="">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: you would need js to do this as there is no parent selector in css

Comment: Can you give me a working snippet sir? @Pete

Comment: Nope, you have not tried anything so your question is too broad and therefore off topic for SO - this is not a free coding service, it is for if you get stuck with a particular piece of code you have written.  Have a go at something and if it doesn't work, come back with a more specific problem, or you can wait for some rep grabber to do your work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this jQuery `change` event:

```js
$(document).on('change', 'select.make', function() {
    if($(this).find(":selected").text()=="Make"){
        $(this).css("color","green");
        $(this).find(":selected").css("color","blue"); 
    }
    else $(this).css("color","red");    
});
```

```css
select {
  color: green;
}

select option {
  color: blue;
}

select option:checked {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="make active">
  <option value="">Make</option>
  <option value="">Saab</option>
  <option value="" selected>Toyoto</option>
  <option value="">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: When the initial value selected it remains the red color sir. I want to avoid that

Comment: No sir. Clearly understand when initial value selected (which is `make`) the `select` tag should be `green` not `red`

Comment: Excellent answer

Comment: Glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need JavaScript for that. You can for example use an eventlistener on the select and add an class for the specific options.

```js
document.querySelector('#variable-select').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  if(e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].value === 'toyota') {
   e.target.classList.add('blue');
  }
})
```

```css
   
.blue {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<select id="variable-select" class="make active">
  <option value="">Make</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="toyota" selected="selected">Toyoto</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

But you can't reliably change the styles of many form elements like the select. Most browsers don't allow styling select elements very much.

Comment: Probably you misunderstood the question

Comment: Maybe, but even after reading it for the third time I can't figure out what you mean exactly with your post. Since the other answer tries to do something similar to mine, maybe you should specify your question a bit

Comment: @Michael and that's why this question shouldn't have been answered - OP not willing to put in any work and just criticises you for trying.  In future, try not to answer off topic questions as the answer provided will usually not be correct due to the OP not giving enough detail, or as in this case the OP giving limited detail and then wanting more and more as each part of their question is answered

Comment: You've got a point. I'll stick to comments next time, until more details are added. Thanks